# Synonym Proposal: [args] -> [arguments]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

I noticed that the [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments) and [args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args) tags, with 6'100 and 400 questions respectively, are not synonyms. I would like to propose that the latter be made into a synonym of the former on Stack Overflow.

[arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments) has a [healthy tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arguments/info), and plenty of questions.

[args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args) has a much more [sparse wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/args/info), and far less questions.

While some of both of these questions would be better off tagged with [command-line-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments), which is very loosely related to [args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args), far more often than not, they are indistinguishable from each other in their usage.

I think we should merge the abbreviation into the word. Unfortunately, I lack the reputation to make the change.

Answer (score 2):

Two remarks:

- These serve two separate masters.  [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments) refer to the arguments passed into a method or function, whereas [args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args) refer *explicitly* to command-line arguments passed in to a program.
- I don't really see the value in [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments) like I do [args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args); one is a necessary thing which really can't stand on its own and has no real definition outside of the context of a specific language (since arguments aren't parameters), and the other has to do with passing values along to a program on the command line, which does have some merit to it.

Misuse of both is rampant, but I don't see these two needing to merge.  In fact, I see burninating [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments), and cleaning up the mess in [args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args).

Comment: I completely agree with your statement about `args`, but very few people will differentiate. And besides, there is the [tag:command-line-arguments] tag for that. Perhaps a note at the top of the `args` tag is needed?

Comment: @Addison:  Or, we could synomize [tag:args] and [tag:command-line-arguments]?

Comment: I might be wrong (a little new here), but wouldn't that make anyone who typed `args` as a tag have it change to `command-line-arguments`? I tested it, and it suggests the synonym, but it doesn't stop you from typing in the literal